# How to use grunt-UglifyJS and sourcemaps?

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs, source-maps

I'm trying to make sourcemaps to play nice while i'm using Grunt and UglifyJS Grunt task.

Here is the current task:

```
uglify: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      sourceMap: function(path) {
        return path + ".map";
      },
    },
    files: {
      'dist/video.min.js': [ 'javascripts/video.js' ]
    }
  }
}
```

What's the problem?

The sourcemap is generated but Chrome is searching for the sourcemap in the wrong location ( that is `dist/dist/video.min.js.map`). I know this because i get 404 in console.

So I edited `dist/video.min.js` and changed `sourceMappingURL` to point to correct location. Now, the sourcemap is loaded but is looking for video.js in completely wrong place: `dist/javascripts/video.js` (that dist again!)

So basically now i'm out of any ideas, just poking the gruntfile with no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that http://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/71 is a potential fix.

Bummer, i always find the solution after i post on SO. This place is magic!